# List to Hashmap using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Can you please help me to construct Hashmap with Objects from ArrayList.

```
public class Store {

    private int storeId;
    private String storeName;
    private int deliveryDays;
    private List<String> servingZipCodes;
    private StoreAddress storeAddress;


    public Store() {
    }

    public Store(int storeId,String storeName,int deliveryDays,List<String> servingZipCodes,StoreAddress storeAddress){
        this.storeId = storeId;
        this.storeName=storeName;
        this.deliveryDays=deliveryDays;
        this.servingZipCodes=servingZipCodes;
        this.storeAddress = storeAddress;
    }

//getters and setters.
}
```

And the StoreAddress class

```
public class StoreAddress {

    private String streetAddress1;
    private String streetAddress2;
    private String streetAddress3;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalCode;
    private String country;
    private String phone;

    public StoreAddress() {
    }

    public StoreAddress(String streetAddress1, String streetAddress2, String streetAddress3, String city, String state, String postalCode, String country, String phone) {
        this.streetAddress1 = streetAddress1;
        this.streetAddress2 = streetAddress2;
        this.streetAddress3 = streetAddress3;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
```

Here is the Test class to for testing.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<Store> storeList=new ArrayList();
        StoreAddress storeAddress1 = new StoreAddress("1500 Polaris Pkwy",null,null,"Columbus","OH","43240","US","9165452345");
        StoreAddress storeAddress2 = new StoreAddress("160 Easton Town Center",null,null,"Columbus","OH","43240","US","9165452345");
        storeList.add(new Store(1,"Store 1",7,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("43240","43241","43242")),storeAddress1));
        storeList.add(new Store(2,"Store 2",7,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("43240","43082","43081")),storeAddress2));
        Map<String,List<Store>> zipCodeStoreList = null;
        storeList.forEach(store -> {
            List<String> servingZipCodes = store.getServingZipCodes();
            servingZipCodes.stream().filter(x -> x.matches(store.getStoreAddress().getPostalCode().substring(0,5))).map(x ->new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
                put(x, store);
            }});
        });
```

Though its possible in Java 7 but looking for solutions in java 8.

```
Key: 43240, value: Store1 , Store2
Key: 43241, value: null
Key: 43242, value: null
Key: 43082, value: null
Key: 43081, value: null
```

Comment: This map's keyset is supposed to be each served zip code, and each value should be the list of stores that serve that zip code?

Comment: Yes thats one I am looking for

Comment: you should know what are you doing at first rather than how. Indeed, you must find out the intersection of `zipCodes` between `Store`s,  and then building the `Map` base on the intersection of `zipCodes`.

Comment: Thanks !! let try that way

Comment: Does it have to be a HashMap?

Comment: Yes,then what the other data structure?

Comment: I was just thinking to return a `List`, but I have a `Map` implementation you can decide if you like it or not.

Answer (score 2):

As I said you should thinking of **what** are you doing first rather than **how**, then the problem is easy to solve. and then you can obtain self-describing code, for example:

```
//             v--- union all zip codes from stores
Stream<String> union = storeList.stream().map(Store::getServingZipCodes)
                                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                                         .distinct();

//             v--- find out intersections between zip codes
Stream<String> intersection = union.filter(zip ->
        storeList.stream().map(Store::getServingZipCodes)
                          .allMatch(it -> it.contains(zip))
);

//                       v--- create a Map simply from intersections 
Map<String, List<Store>> result = intersection.collect(toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        unused -> storeList
));
```

### Output

```
assert result.get("43240") == [store1, store2];
assert result.get("others") == null;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is first,  filter the `List` for `Store`s with a given zip code. This given zip code is the variable name `key`. I then use the key to put the resulting filter into the `Map` variable `zipCodeStoreList`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Test
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Store> storeList=new ArrayList();
        StoreAddress storeAddress1 = new StoreAddress("1500 Polaris Pkwy",null,null,"Columbus","OH","43240","US","9165452345");
        StoreAddress storeAddress2 = new StoreAddress("160 Easton Town Center",null,null,"Columbus","OH","43240","US","9165452345");

        storeList.add(new Store(1,"Store 1",7,new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("43240","43241","43242")),storeAddress1));
        storeList.add(new Store(2,"Store 2",7,new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("43240","43082","43081")),storeAddress2));
        Map<String,List<Store>> zipCodeStoreList = new HashMap();

        String key = "43241";//See if a Store associates with this zip code.
        //Add the key and the results from filtering the storeList based on the key.
        zipCodeStoreList.put(key, storeList.stream().filter(x -> x.getServingZipCodes().contains(key)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        //Print results
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<Store>> entry : zipCodeStoreList.entrySet())
        {
            for(Store store : entry.getValue())
            {
                System.out.println("filter 1: " + entry.getKey() + " - " + store.getStoreName());
            }
        }        
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

> Altered Version that lists all of the `Stores` associated with a particular zip code.

**Remove**

```
    String key = "43081";
    zipCodeStoreList.put(key, storeList.stream().filter(x -> x.getServingZipCodes().contains(key)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**Replace with**

```
    //Add the zip code belong to at least one store plus a zip code that belongs to no store.
    List<String> allZipCodes = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("43240","43082","43081", "43240","43241","43242", "55555"));
    for(String zipCode : allZipCodes)
    {
        zipCodeStoreList.put(zipCode, storeList.stream().filter(x -> x.getServingZipCodes().contains(zipCode)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks all let me implement

Comment: You can copy the text of the output panel into your browser; there is no need to do a screenshot and upload pictures.